# search every word in string with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search every word of an string in the database. If an word exist it needs to be highlighted. The current script works, but needs a lot of memory for my server. I don't know how i make it easier, but maybe do you?

```
<?php

$total_messages = $_POST['total'] - 1;

for($x = 0; $x <= $total_messages; $x++)
{
    //Search highlights
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM highlights WHERE enabled=1")
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        //Vars for highlights
        $highlight_txt = $row['value'];
        $highlight_type = $row['type'];
        $highlight_color = "black";
        $highlight_title = null;

        //If the text isnt empty
        if($highlight_txt != null || $highlight_txt != "")
        {
            //Type highlights
            if($highlight_type == "tree") //Tree type
            {
                $highlight_type = "18"; //Category number
                $highlight_background = "pink"; //Background
                if($row['option1'] != null)
                {                       
                    $highlight_title = htmlentities($row['option1']);
                }
            }           
            else
            {
                $highlight_background = "yellow"; //Background
            }

            //Add highlight
            $message = preg_replace("/\b($highlight_txt)\b/i", "<span class='bc_highlight' highlight-type='$highlight_type' highlight-value='$highlight_txt' style='background: $highlight_background; color: $highlight_color;' title=''>$highlight_txt</span>", $message);    
        }       
    }   
    echo $message; //Display the message
}
```

Comment: wheres `$message` being defined?

Comment: Is your problem the amount of memory consumed by the script or the time it takes to run?

Comment: Just as a general tip: translating the comments makes it usually easier for anyone to understand your code and therefor help you with your problem.

Comment: $messages is previously defined. But to make it more understandable i removed it.
I translated the commands in this script

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something like this?

```
$messages = ["This is my message1","This is my message2"];
$highlights = [];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM highlights WHERE enabled=1")
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $highlights[$row["value"]] = [
        "type" => $row["type"],
        "color" => $row["color"]
    ];
}
$callback = function($matches) use ($highlights) {
  $word = $matches[1];
  if(isset($highlights[$word])) {
      $highlight = $highlights[$word];
      return sprintf('<span style="color:%s">%s</span>',$highlight["color"],$word);
  } else {
      return $word;
  }
};
foreach($messages as &$message) {
    $message = preg_replace_callback("/(\w+)/i",$message,$callback);
}
```

Comment: This is better to use, because it's smaller. But will this also use less memory? It's like 10 messages and 30 words per messages. Also there are 7237 highlight words.

Comment: Yes, for two reasons. 1) Read out all the hightlights once from the DB. 2) Search through each message only once for all the highlights to replace.